# Label del input no se desliza al hacer click sobre el texto de la etiqueta

Tags: materialize

Tengo un input que se visualiza de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando hago click justo encima del label `Secuencia` el input no desliza el label hacia arriba para conseguir el efecto de la imagen siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si se clickea en otro lugar del input sin problemas desliza el label.

```html
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 <form action="" method="post">
     <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input name="secuencia" type="text">
      <label for="secuencia">Secuencia</label>
    </div>
       </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: mmm ... creo que a mi sí me funciona cuando lo ejecuto aquí

Comment: Funciona si haces click en otro lugar que no sea justo encima de la etiqueta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es porque el input necesita un id para que el label haga referencia.

```
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <form action="" method="post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <input id="secuencia" name="secuencia" type="text">
        <label for="secuencia">Secuencia</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Enlace a codepen: https://codepen.io/renzo-brian-telenta-visconte/pen/agpyXL

Comment: Efectivamente, ahora le coloqué el id y funciona a la perfección. Muchas Gracias!